# Ionic application targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

I am creating an android application using ionic 3, when i attempt to upload to playstore i get an error that my app targets api 25, when i check my project.property the value of target =android-26, same with my androidManifest.xml the value of targetSdkVersion = 26, how do i set the target again. Below is my ionic info

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0 (C:\Users\IETECH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You need to install android platform 26, and then change `android:targetSdkVersion="26"` in the `<uses-sdk>` tag in `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file in the Ionic 3 application folder.

You should then be able to create a new release build and upload the app to Play Store successfully.

Alternatively, if you upgrade cordova to the latest version, a fresh cordova build will create the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with `android:targetSdkVersion="26"`.

Answer (score 1):

Open your config.xml in the root folder of the project and adjust version accordingly in the following section:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="25" />
...
```

Basically update the value to what your min bar is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build using a specific android version? What versions have you installed to Android Studio? Maybe you  built using a version provided automatically and somewhere in your config you had another version specified. Anyway cant answer with that information. When you build the app you get no errors?

Comment: i have 24, 25, 26, 27 and 28 installed both Android sdk build tools, and sdk platforms, how do i know which version is default and how can i change it?

Comment: when you run ionic cordova build android the cmd tells you which version its about to use. you can use another version when you add the platform like ionic cordova platform add android@5.0.0